# Poisson Binomial upper tail decreases when all succes probabilities decrease?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have Poisson Binomial r.v. $K$ with success probabilities $p_{1},\ldots,p_{n}$, where $n$ is odd and $p_{i}\in(0,1)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Let $F=\mathbb{P}[K\geq\frac{n+1}{2}]$, that is, $F$ is the probability that at least majority of the trials are successful. I am trying to prove, without success so far, that if all the $p_{i}$'s decrease, then $F$ decreases. I would appreciate any suggestion (or reference).

Thanks in advance.